# Laravel use all Entries from DB in Select Box

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu

YOu can create a select Box like this:

```
{{ Form::select('age', ['Under 18', '19 to 30', 'Over 30']) }}
```

Lets say I want to have a select box of all my users (saved in the DB). How can I do that? I've got a `User`-Model.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
use App\Entities\User;
public function getUsers(User $user)
{
    $allUsers = $user->lists('name', 'id');
    return view('users.view',compact('allUsers'));
}
```

In your blade

```
{!! Form::select('users[]', $allUsers,null , ['multiple'=>'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```